# Sending list information for google charts properly via flask to JS?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, google-visualization

I'm mapping out ratings against episodes on a scatterplot on Google Charts. I have properly set the code up to send

```
data = [1, 8.7],[2, 8.8],[3, 8.3],[4, 8.4],[5, 9.3],[6, 8.9],[8, 9.3],[9, 8.4],[10, 8.3],[11, 8.4],[12, 8.9],[13, 8.7],[14, 9.2],[15, 9.1],[16, 8.6],[17, 8.9],[18, 9.3],[19, 9.3],[21, 8.7],[22, 8.5],[23, 8.3],[24, 8.7],[25, 9.3],[26, 9.6],[27, 8.8],[28, 8.5],[29, 7.8],[30, 8.5],[31, 9.5],[32, 9.7],[34, 8.3],[35, 8.1],[36, 8.7],[37, 8.7],[38, 8.5],[39, 8.9],[40, 9.3],[41, 8.9],[42, 9.6]
```

From Python to my graph.

Python:

```
def SendtoHTML():

  dataPoint = data
  return render_template('Scatter.html', series = series,finalEpNum = finalEpNum,minRatingFinal = minRatingFinal ,dataPoint = dataPoint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Script:

```
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var series = '{{series}}';
    var finalEpNum = '{{finalEpNum}}'
    var minRatingFinal = '{{minRatingFinal}}'
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Episode', 'Rating'],
    ]);

    var options = {

      title: series,
      hAxis: {title: 'Episode', minValue: 1, maxValue: finalEpNum},
      vAxis: {title: 'Rating', minValue: minRatingFinal , maxValue: 10},
      legend: true
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data1, options);
  }
```

Which currently creates [a google charts graph with all blue points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVhf6.png) 
However, I want to change colors of the datapoints after a given [x] value until another given [x] value. Kinda [like this graph I made in matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgCZq.png) where the colors change from blue to red after season 1 ends. How would I achieve this in python or JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [style](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) column role

in your JS, add the role as the last column heading.
(the style role should follow the series column it represents)

```
var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Episode', 'Rating', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}],  // <-- add style role
]);
```

then in your data, you can add the color each point should be...

```
data = [1, 8.7, 'blue'],[2, 8.8, 'blue'],[3, 8.3, 'blue'],[4, 8.4, 'red'],[5, 9.3, 'red'],[6, 8.9, 'orange'],[8, 9.3, 'orange'],[9, 8.4, 'orange'],
```

Comment: This works whenever I hardcode that data into JS. However I get the error Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string for whenever I try importing from python

Comment: where do you add the data to the data table? --> `data1 `

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code now after properly formatting the data block.

Python

```
def SendtoHTML():
 finalEpNumParsable = int(finalEpNum)
 datapointTest = [[1, 8.7, "0000ff"],[2, 6.7, "orange"],[3, 8.7, "0000ff"],[4,6.7,'red']]
 render = render_template('Scatter.html', dataPoint = datapointTest)
 return render
```

JS

```
    function drawChart() {
    var dataPoint = {{ dataPoint | tojson }};
    var series = '{{series}}';
    var finalEpUnparsed = {{finalEpNum}}
    var finalEpNum = parseInt(finalEpUnparsed, 10);

    var minRatingFinal = '{{minRatingFinal}}'
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Episode', 'Rating', { role: 'style', type: 'string' }],  // <-- add style role
        dataPoint[0]

    ]);
    for (i = 1; i < finalEpNum-5; i++){
    data1.addRows([dataPoint[i]]);}
```